# Approximate solution to MILP with PuLP

Tags: python, pulp

Is it possible to get an approximate solution to a mixed integer linear programming problem with PuLP? My problem is complex and the exact resolution takes too long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably do not mean Linear Programming but rather Mixed Integer Programming. (The original question asked about LPs).

LPs usually solve quite fast and I don't know a good way to find an approximate solution for them. You may want to try an interior point or barrier method and set an iteration or time limit. For Simplex methods this typically does not work very well.

MIP models can take a lot of time to solve. Solvers allow to terminate earlier by setting a gap (gap = 0 means solving to optimality). E.g.

`model.solve(GLPK(options=['--mipgap', '0.01']))`

Comment: Yes sorry I meant Mixed Integer Programming. Do you know if there is a way to set a gap with PuLP?